# StackEngine - facebook app to embed reputation, badges, etc. from user Stack Exchange Accounts to profile tab

Tags: app, facebook

#### About

*What is Stack Engine*?
All profiles on Facebook have tabs. For example, users have a 'Photos' tab and a 'Links' tab by default. 
StackEngine is an application for Facebook to embed reputation, earned badges, etc. from user Stack Exchange Accounts to StackEngine [application tab](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs) on user profile. Your friend can check out the StackEngine profile tab to know what you’re doing on Stack Exchange, and the friend can click back to your canvas page. Let friends know your flair.

#### Screenshots

*Application Profile Tab*
[image]
[image]

See more screenshots [here](http://www.picasaweb.google.com/vladjan/StackEngine)

#### Access

[Application profile on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=146982688648222)

**Help**
[Instructions for adding this Application to your profile](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=146982688648222&v=info)

#### Platform

Facebook Application (canvas page in an iframe)

#### Contact

Created by me (Vladislav Tserman) in spare time.
Leave your feedback and bug reports on 'Reviews' tab on application profile on facebook.
I'm available at: vladjan (at) gmail.com

#### Code

Written in Java, Google Web Toolkit under Eclipse Helios. Powered by Google App Engine for Java. 
Objectify framework used for datastore instead of JPA/JDO
Facebook-java-api used to access facebook API
Thanks to creators of StackWrap4J - a Java wrapper for the Stack Exchange API

#### Changelog

v1.0.27
*– Added ability to view Recent Questions for any connected profile. Just click on username, additional tab with 5 recent questions should appear. 
Clicking on question's title should redirect you to the question at appropriate Stack Exchange site. [Screenshot](http://picasaweb.google.com.ua/lh/photo/ixRpek2bUko_u4cuVKcJ4w?feat=directlink)*
*– Couple bugfixes*

**Future**
*I'm working on adding new features. **Any suggestions for improvements/features to add?***

Is it worth to add the ability for application to post to a user's stream whenever user ask/answer/comment/favorites question, awarded badges, etc. on Stack Exchange sites connected to Facebook via application?
One major drawback is that to support such feature Extended Publishing Permissions ( publish_stream, offline_access) will be required.

Comment: My profile is not adding. It is showing: "Oops! Something went wrong while processing your request."

Comment: I found defect in code. Problem happens during processing Post-Authorize Callback request from facebook. Now defect is fixed. You can try to re-authorize application. Go to Application Settings on facebook and delete StackEngine application, then go apps.facebook.com/stackengine. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Now another problems happen. When I am trying to open the link http://apps.facebook.com/stackengine/ , it is showing an error "Oops! Something went wrong: Can't find your account. Try to reauthorize application." It works after deleting and retying add application. But in the profile page showing "Status: Authorization required".

Comment: Chanchal, thanks for your feedback. Now should work like a charm.

Comment: Adding a profile tab does not work for me. For about one week now, it only says "An error occurred while trying to add the application to your profile. Please try again later." after clicking the confirmation button (second Add Profile Tab) - Additionally, the German umlaut in my name suffers from a bad character encoding and is not displayed correctly. This might have something to do with the problem?

Comment: When trying to add the profile tab, I am getting "An error occurred while trying to add the application to your profile. Please try again later". It does this no matter how many times I try :(

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to add HTTPS support